# Trying to pass 3d array to function c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to pass a 3d array to a function.  I have more to do in the function, but I cannot seem to get the array from the main function to the void function.

It must be something simple I am missing as I am still learning a lot. Just a quick explanation on what I am doing wrong with the function printMonthlySales in the main function would mean a lot.

Also the void function must be a float array and the main function must use the float array.

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <iomanip>;

using namespace std;

const int NUM_DEPTS = 2;
const int NUM_STORES = 2;
const int NUM_MONTHS = 12;

void printMonthlySales(int a, float array[2][12][2]);

int main() {
    char sentinel = 'y';
    int userInput = 0;
    float storeMonthlySales[NUM_STORES][NUM_MONTHS][NUM_DEPTS] = { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2,
                                                                2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2,
                                                                3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2,
                                                                2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 };
    while (sentinel == 'y' || sentinel == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "1. January" << endl;
        cout << "2. February" << endl;
        cout << "3. March" << endl;
        cout << "4. April" << endl;
        cout << "5. May" << endl;
        cout << "6. June" << endl;
        cout << "7. July" << endl;
        cout << "8. August" << endl;
        cout << "9. September" << endl;
        cout << "10.October" << endl;
        cout << "11.November" << endl;
        cout << "12.December" << endl;
        cout << "Please select a month using 1-12: ";
        cin >> userInput;
        printMonthlySales(userInput, storeMonthlySales[NUM_STORES][NUM_MONTHS][NUM_DEPTS]);
    }
    

    return 0;
}

void printMonthlySales(int a, float array[2][12][2])
{
    int b = a;
    const int m = 12;
    float sumStoreOne = 0;
    float sumStoreTwo = 0;
    float sumDepartmentOne = 0;
    float sumDepartmentTwo = 0;
    float totalSales = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][b][j] << endl;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use `printMonthlySales(userInput, storeMonthlySales);`. That will forward the array correctly. The current call passes only one float because you indexed into the array, moreover with out of bounds indices. Just a note, enable warnings in your compiler - `-Wall -Wextra -pendatic -Werror` for gcc,clang; you have extra semicolons after `#include`.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326021/how-to-pass-a-3d-array-as-a-parameter-to-function-c-also-do-global-variables/13326246

Comment: Quimby - Thank you very much.